# Messed up jQuery code not sending through AJAX post

Tags: jquery

I am using `$.post()` to input some data into a server. Within the ajax file I want to add a 1 to a variable containing a number. However, when the data is put into the server, instead of adding a 1 it instead puts 1. I feel stumped by this. What am I doing wrong. I swear for a second I got it to work, then next thing I know it stops working. Here is the code.

```
$liker = $_POST['likes'];

$likes = $liker + 1; 

send_data_to_server($likes);
```

Update

I have figured out that the likes is not being sent through the ajax post. I will try to troubleshoot a solution since I see the jquery code is not acting right. Here is the code below if anyone wants to give it a shot while I troubleshoot it on my own.

```
$('#submitter').click(function() {
    var search_term = $('#band_request').val();
    $.post('ajax_searchlike.php', {
        search_term: search_term
    }, function(data) {
    /*this section is where I know the problem is
      $('#like_temp_holder').append(data);
      });
      var likes = $('#like_temp_holder').val();
      */
        $.post('ajax_send_band_request.php', {
            likes: likes
        }, function(data) {
            $(data).appendTo("#response_from_request_verification");
        });
    });​

< /script>
    <div id="like_temp_holder"></div>
    <div id = "response_from_request_verification"></div>​
```

Comment: So what is `$_POST['likes']`? Don't guess

Comment: If `$_POST['likes']` doesn't contain something PHP can parse as an integer, it will be converted to `0`, yielding `0 + 1`. You should do some basic debugging. Start with `var_dump($_POST)`.

Comment: `$_POST['likes']` sent through the ajax `$.post()` is the number 77, at least in my working example.

Comment: It contains the number 1. As for echoing out $liker nothing is returned to me.

Comment: echo the value of `$likes` before calling `send_data_to_server()`

Comment: Try using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) console with Firefox to analyze the post request and see what is going wrong.

Comment: Did so. Everything worked but the likes was returning with nothing attached to it. The post source data from Firebug shows `likes=`

Comment: So are you trying to make 2 separate post requests on the same event? Or are you trying to do one after the other?

Comment: When I click on a button, I want to do two ajax posts one after another.

Comment: Then prevent the default submission first by returning `false`. But this way you can't ensure which executes first, since `ajax` is `async`. Try to call the second ajax within the first's success. Or try jquery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: Let me explain what I'm exactly trying to do. The first $.post() calls up the data called likes. I then attach likes to the second $.post() to be inserted into the database. I want both $.post() to operate when I click on the button with the id submitter.

Comment: Solved. Thanks everyone for the help and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my fault. The first .post() is pointless. I attached the first ajax file to the second and got the job done. I like to go AJAX overboard. Lesson learned: why make multiple AJAX calls when you can simply do one.

Answer (score 0):

how about kicking out the likes and just do this:

```
$liker = $_POST['likes'];

$liker++ ; 

send_data_to_server($liker);
```

or does this attempt break your code?

Comment: Tried it. I found out that it's not the php but actually the jquery. Thanks for the help though.